I've some difficulty with Aspect Ratio and Orthographic Camera Settings with Blender 4.2.2
Dear Blender Community,
I’m encountering a strange problem with the Aspect Ratio in Blender 4.2.2. Let me explain further.
I have created a series of renders of a character using an Orthographic Camera. For your information, I save the renders as .png images with a color depth of 8. Specifically, I have created renders with the following characteristics:
In the Output Properties, I have set the pixel values as follows: X=514 and Y=562, essentially creating a square. I have not adjusted any other values in this menu.
In the Object Data Properties of the camera, I have clearly switched to Orthographic view and set the Scale value to 22.800 so that my mesh appears well visible and detailed in the center of this ‘square.’
For the first 7/8 renders/images, everything was fine… but then, needing more field of view in width (and not height), I couldn’t go beyond 562 pixels in X because, instead of continuing to increase, the height restricts. It’s as if there is a constraint on the Aspect Ratio.
I am fully aware that I can adjust the Orthographic Scale, but the resulting render/image would be smaller and less detailed.
Without having to resort to post-production, how can I resolve this issue? How can I increase the pixels only in X (in width, to be clear) without altering the height?
Thank you for any help!

Well, the question is already marked as duplicate, but the short version of the linked answer is as follows: under the camera's Object Data Properties, go to Camera > Sensor Fit and switch from Auto to Vertical. This lets you change the width without affecting the height of the field of view. If for any reason you would want to change the height without affecting the width, set Sensor Fit to Horizontal.
